# Clustering a labeled data set

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I have a large labeled dataset with 29 classes. Is is possible to use a clustering algorithm (like k-means) in this dataset, or it's not possible since clustering algorithms are unsupervised ?

Comment: what do you mean by classes? Is it categorical data for you have 29 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do many things:

- Forget about the labels: just use the features that are not labels and cluster along those features using the k-means algorithm (or another).
- Forget about the features: this is the dummiest way of clustering. Cluster the data in 29 clusters according to the labels that they have. If you want less clusters, you can compute the centroids of the classes and use them to join clusters of different labels.
- Use everything: create a categorical variable refering to the class that every example belongs to. Then, with this new variable and all the features perform a classical clustering algorithm.

The way to proceed depends on if you want to use the labels or not, and how much importance you want them to have.

Comment: So the first point is about discovering patterns in the dataset. But what kind of patterns for example?
And the second point is about aggregating pre-existing classes into new classes. Am i correct ?

Comment: Second point: right. First point is to discover the clusters that arise when not thinking about the labels, to find patters on the features themselves. It discovers the patterns that clustering usually discovers: that is, how are features distributed in different connected components.

Comment: So isnt directly connected to classification ?

Comment: Perhaps, or perhaps not. If your data is linearly separable, probably your clusters will look like the labels. If not, then the clusters see some things and the labels others.

Comment: I have a question. Let's say the task is to describe the dataset using a "label" column. Would you use classification or clustering? From what I know, classification doesn't tell you how they cluster the data in order to give you the prediction. But on the other hand, it isn't best practise to cluster labelled data.